# Dynamically assign ID of query to anchor id attribute

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am populating a DataTable in Laravel with the results of an Inner Join query. After, that I am generating update buttons which will allow me to edit the selected record. I would like to use the id of each record returned from the Join query to be unique row id. The issue is, the query returns an array of objects so I am not sure how to access each id.

I've tried using  a foreach loop, the buttons generate but they become unclickable.

Query:

```php
$payment = DB::table('owed_payments')
    ->join('payments', 'sub_id', '=', 'payments.user_id')
    ->join('user_profiles', 'sub_id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id')
    ->select(
        'owed_payments.id',
        'owed_payments.sub_id',
        'owed_payments.company_name',
        'owed_payments.amount',
        'user_profiles.first_name',
        'user_profiles.last_name',
        'owed_payments.status',
        'owed_payments.job_date',
        'owed_payments.amount_payed',
        'owed_payments.date_payed',
        'payments.trn_ss',
        'payments.nis',
        'payments.account_number',
        'payments.bank_name',
        'payments.bank_branch'
    )
    ->get();
```

Code to generate update buttons:

```php
return DataTables::of($payment)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($payment) {
        foreach ($payment as $pay) {
            return '<a href="#" class="edit btn" id="' . $pay['id'] . '">Update</a>';
        }
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
```

Comment: `addColumn` will be run for each row so you should not need a foreach loop, you can access the `id` with `$payment->id`

Comment: Thank you this works! I was trying earlier but got an error that's why I used foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addcolumn` will be run for every row, therefore you don't need a `foreach` loop.

You can directly access the `id` with `$payment->id`:

```php
return DataTables::of($payment)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($payment) {
        return "<a href='#' class='edit btn' id='{$payment->id}'>Update</a>";
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
```